# Why is this solution to the mountain 'puzzle-in-a-puzzle' incorrect?

Tags: the-witness

**Spoilers - this occurs after you open the endgame box at the top of the mountain**

> [image: Why is this wrong!?]

As far as I can tell, this should be correct.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Oh I see:

> The piece that is rotatable in the smaller puzzle becomes non-rotatable in the larger puzzle.  I simply had to solve it again with the correct rotation.